# When to use schema instance methods and statics

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I understand that Methods adds an instance method to documents whereas Statics adds static "class" methods to the Models itself. However, I do not understand when to use an instance and when to use static class.

On what occasions should I create an instance and attach methods and on what occasions should I attach static functions to the model itself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scenarios when you need to play with the documents(mongoose instance objects) of a collection will need **instance methods**. Best example for this could be comparing passwords, or validating other keys. Also instance methods are used in cases where you first fetches the data and then need to execute your method.

On the other hand **static methods** are used when you wants to implement some functionality based on the available model methods. Best example for using this could be, Lets say you have an schema which has a **name** field, and you are doing so many queries on this field. In such cases you can create an static method like **findByName()**(or something) on top of mongoose **find()** method which will do this specific job.

hope this helps :)